# Need help to get NzbDrone to autostart

Tags: raspbian

I installed NzbDrone on my Raspberry Pi, running Raspbian, using [this tutorial](http://www.raspberrypihelp.net/tutorials/52-nzbdrone-raspberry-pi).

I want to make sure it starts when I boot up my Raspberry Pi so I followed [these instructions](https://github.com/NzbDrone/NzbDrone/wiki/Autostart-on-Linux) (Method 1) 
I edited the `nzbdrone.conf` and put `setuid pi`.

However, Iit doesn't start when I boot up my Pi. Any idea what could be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

By default Rasbian doesn't use upstart, and instead uses the traditional Sys V init system. Try method 2 and edit `/etc/rc.local`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same exact issue. I resolved it and documented the install on Raspbian from start to finish. It had to do with how mono needed to be executed in the upstart script. You have to specify the full path of mono in the upstart script.
[Install Nzbdrone Raspberry Pi](http://www.htpcguides.com/install-nzbdrone-raspberry-pi-raspbian/)